# How insert word into simple hash function C

Tags: c, function, hash, compiler-errors

Noob, trying to figure out how to insert 1 word into a simple hash table (which is given). The word is lowercase. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
""exit status 1
main.c:30:40: error: function definition is not allowed here
    unsigned int hash(const char *word){""
```

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N = 26;
    // Length = 45;

    // Represents a node in a hash table
    typedef struct node
    {
        // LENGTH is defined in dictionary.h as 45, max length
        char word[45+1];
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;

    // Represents a hash table, N is defined as 26 above
    node *hashtable[N];

    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    char *word = "jello";

    // Hashes word to a number between 0 (a) and 25 (z), inclusive, based on its first letter, creating 26 buckets, or alphabetized categories

    unsigned int hash(const char *word){
        return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
    }

    int x = word[0] - 'a';

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    printf("%c\n", word[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function definitions should be outside of `main` (or any other function).

Comment: Easy fix to my code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you're defining a function in a place you aren't supposed to - in this case, inside the `main` function. Move it out of there and you should be OK.